# Querying NoSQL from Java & Performance Differences Between Direct & Indirect Querying

Tags: java, mongodb, neo4j, jdo, nosql

I have just started researching *NoSQL* and would like to ask the following questions:

1. Just like SQL is the direct query language for ALL RMDBS, then what is the direct query language for all *NoSQL* databases?  If there isn't one direct language, then what query languages exist - a list of a few query languages will suffice.
2. Similar to question 1. above, does Java have a standard query language for all *NoSQL* databases?
3. Is there a significant peformance differentiation when using JDO/Datanucleus or Spring Data when compared with direct NoSQL queries on either MongoDB and/or Neo4J?  For example, in terms of RMDBS, writing direct SQL via JDBC when compared to using JPA/ORM Tool, there is significant performance difference in favour of direct SQL.

The reason why I am asking these questions is to offset the advantages of cross-compatibility by using JDO/Datanucleus versus Performance loss or gains?

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about too many questions at the same time

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg But they are all related to difference between JDO/Datanucleus vs Direct and gave SQL as an example (so that I can understand the differences).

Comment: @PeterMmm My question is about JDO/Datanucleus and NoSQL

Comment: *NoSQL* is an umbrella term for a general class of databases that doesn't rely on relational technology or SQL language. There are dozens, if not hundreds, of NoSQL databases, with different categories (graph, document, key/value, column). There is simply no single (or simple) answer to this question. Performance is based on data schema and related code, combined with engine-specific optimizations and specialties. Query languages are engine-specific. I'd suggest reading a book like Fowler's 'NoSQL Distilled' to gain a better understanding of the overall topic.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg According to the terms & conditions: I __can__ ask questions on software tools commonly used by programmers and practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development.  So why is this question put on hold as it talks about Datanucleus and discussing performance issues between direct query and using a Persistence Framework.

Comment: @Jamie It's not **what** you ask about that was the issue, it's **how** you ask about it. You had five questions within one question. On StackOverflow it is often preferable to have "one question per question". But I have to say that your edit is an improvement (only asking three questions instead of five). Your question might be reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, there are no standard in NoSQL.

If you choose NoSQL for performance, adding any layer will likely impact it. For that reason, most NoSQL providers prefer providing 'drivers' per language that try to keep performance up and give you an easy way to access their data.

There is a recent effort from 28io to create a language to query across many NoSQL databases. The language is called JSONiq.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  May I ask if Spring Data MongoDB/Neo4J uses direct queries via the provider's drivers?  And if so, would you think that Spring Data might generate more performant queries than me as I am new to this game?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a big response but it seemed like I wasn't addressing the specifics of your questions and had strong (good) opinions about Morphia.

I looked and looked for something fairly easy to use with Mongo and came across Morphia. I've never looked any where else because its so easy to use.

Your questions remind me of the complexities of SQL.  I worked the past two days on five MySql Tables that had joins throughout the queries.  I could hear a little voice in the back of my head that says: 'priority level of getting this Morphia/Mongo -ized increasing every second.'

https://github.com/mongodb/morphia

```
<!--pom.xml depenency entry -->
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb.morphia</groupId>
        <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
    <version>0.105</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: http://blog.mongodb.org/post/55165338565/morphia-version-0-101-released   <-- an article around July when Mongo took on Morphia.